# Why QECC amplitude damping error syndrome and qiskit simulation are different?

Tags: qiskit, error-correction, stabilizer-code

The [[3,0,2]] code, stabilizers are X<sub>1</sub>Z<sub>2</sub>I<sub>3</sub>,Z<sub>1</sub>X<sub>2</sub>Z<sub>3</sub>,I<sub>1</sub>Z<sub>2</sub>X<sub>3</sub>.
Use the circuit to decode and measure stabilizers:
[image]

As for amplitude damping error syndrome,  use $\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{1-\gamma}\end{array}\right], \quad\left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & \sqrt{\gamma} \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right], \gamma=1$

$\rho \prime=E_0 \rho E_0^{\dagger}+E_1 \rho E_1^{\dagger}$, $
\langle S\rangle_\rho=\operatorname{Tr}(\rho S)
$ to compute.

The result is :
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
 & \mathrm{X}_{\mathrm{a}} \mathrm{Z}_{\mathrm{b}} \mathrm{I}_{\mathrm{c}} & \mathrm{Z}_{\mathrm{a}} \mathrm{X}_{\mathrm{b}} \mathrm{Z}_{\mathrm{c}} & \mathrm{I}_{\mathrm{a}} \mathrm{Z}_{\mathrm{b}} \mathrm{X}_{\mathrm{c}} \\
\hline ap_{a} & 0 & 0 & +1 \\
\hline ap_{b} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline ap_{c} & +1 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}
$$

Then simulate the circuit in qiskit.
Add  amplitude damping error to one of the three qubit, get the result:

Add  amplitude damping error to q0(a):

[image] which is the same as error syndrome.(The stabilizer order is from top to bottom)

But for q1(b):

[image]
The result is +1  0  0  , but the syndrome is 0  0  0.

For q2(c):

[image]
The result is +1  +1  0  , but the syndrome is +1  0  0.

Why the results don't correspond ?
And where my mistake was in the process?

```
#add identity gates to qubit and add amplitude damping error
p = 1
amplitude_error = amplitude_damping_error(p)
noise_model = NoiseModel()
noise_model.add_quantum_error(amplitude_error, ['id'], [2])

simulator = provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')
noise_job = execute(circuit, backend=simulator, shots=8192, optimization_level = 0, noise_model=noise_model)
result = noise_job.result()  
counts = result.get_counts()
plot_histogram(counts)
```

Comment: Can you show your Qiskit code for performing the amplitude dampening and the results?

Comment: I have re-edited and added the code. Thank you.

Comment: Is the error being applied after every gate? It looks like you are trying to do the Hadamard Tests of those operators on the density matrix that is the result of the error being applied to the state created by the 3 Hadamards and opening two CZs: if the error is occurring during the preparation of this state then it would never reach that point.

Comment: Error is applied after every gate. Thank you for your help!! You are right!